# Install additional kernel modules

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, kernel-module, debian-based

I need `pwm-bl.ko` kernel module for my Raspberry Pi, but it is not present in my `/lib/modules` directory. Sure, I can download kernel sources for my kernel version, select necessary modules to build, build and put it into this directory. But how to automate this process? I've found `module-assistant` utility, but it looks like a list of modules is very limited.

Comment: Use `dkms` https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support But the question is rather strange. How did you get your binary (compiled) kernel in the first place?

Comment: Thank you! I use standard Raspbian distro, and I need an additional backlight driver for my system.

Comment: And they didn't build modules? I can suspect they have done it for sake of the minimizing the size, so, they have to provide a solution how to add modules...

Comment: In `/lib/modules/4.19.75-v7+/kernel/drivers/video/backlight` I see `rpi_backlight.ko` and `lcd.ko`, so yes, I think they selected only very necessary modules.

Comment: Hm, it looks like DKMS is not very suitable for building in-tree modules :(

Comment: I didn't find any requirements of that module that prevent to build it out of tree. So, dkms will be able to handle this.